# How to make a div box with display:flex clickable like display:block?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the box divs be clickable, but the code I'm using is

```
display:flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

to center the text horizontally because when I use display:block, the text won't center horizontally if it's long.

I have a demo here http://jsfiddle.net/UHECE/32/

When you try to click the right div, you have to point the mouse over the text. I want the whole right div to be clickable (link like the text) regardless of the length of the text. As for the left div, you can hover anywhere on the div and it will be clickable because the text is long. I think it depends on the width of text, because when I tried to use Firebug and hover over the text on the right div, the height is 100%, but the width depends on the length of text. Does anyone know how to make the divs a clickable link?

As much as possible I'd like to stick with a CSS code please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link tag in the right box is not filling the entire width.  That's why you need to click the text (or above or below the text).

By adding `display:block;` and `width:100%;` to the link element, it's now filling the entire right box.

Updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/UHECE/33/

Answer (score 1):

you should add this to your css file:

```
#rightq{
    margin-top:50%;
    margin-right:20%;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

you wanted to select an ID with a `.` but thats not possible :).